# Forgot sudo password in MANJARO

Tags: passwords, sudo, manjaro

Currently,I am using Manjaro linux for the first time so i don't know how to work with commands.I accidentally set a sudo password and now,i forgot my sudo password. How can i change it or get it so i can do my work with command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your filesystems aren't encrypted, you can always boot a live OS (typically the original install media you used will suffice), mount your root (/) partition, `chroot` into it, and use `passwd` as required to change passwords. This is why physical security of an installation is important (and it is even if you *do* encrypt your filesystems).

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reset_lost_root_password